# Anaconda 3 installation was not successful

Tags: python, installation, windows-10, anaconda, conda

I tried to install Anaconda 3 Python 3.7 64-bit on my Windows 10 computer. Install finishes correctly, but the destination folder doesn't have *conda.exe* or the *Scripts* folder.

It has _conda.exe and uninstall exe's and conda-meta, Lib and pkgs folders.

I also tried:

- 32-bit version. Same result.
- miniconda installation. The same...

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, if something does weird things like this, you have a broken Windows search for "media creation tools" or you don't have enough space on disk C.

Answer (score 0):

Your installation has been completed. You can confirm this by searching "Anaconda Prompt" from the startup menu.

This is not a problem at all. You just didn't find the right place. The command `conda` is from **subfolder** `condabin\conda.bat` or `Scripts\conda.exe`, depending on [the options you checked](https://docs.anaconda.com/_images/win-install-options.png) during installation.

If you install miniconda as admin, find the subfolders under

```
C:\ProgramData\miniconda3
```

If you install it as a normal user, it may be stored here

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3
```

Comment: Retried the installation in both user modes. No 'Continuum', Script or condabin folders were created. In 'C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3' there are only conda-meta, Lib and pkgs folders, _conda.exe and Uninstall-Miniconda3.exe execs.